# Seekbar in RecyclerView returns last position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, avaudioplayer, android-seekbar

Well, I'm having Recyclerview containing audio files, Audio playing is working fine but seekbar is not updating, when i click at any item! last position item seekbar is getting updating and playing. I didn't find the exact solution. Here is my code.

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class AudiorecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AudiorecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private List<GettingAudio> datalist;
    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    private Context context;
    Activity act;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private String BASE_URL = "http://zuman.e3.amazon/";
    private String medialink,titlestring;
    private int downloadedSize = 0 ;
    TextView cur_val;
    SeekBar seek;

    private int totalSize = 0;
    public AudiorecyclerAdapter(Context context,Activity act,List<GettingAudio> list){
        this.datalist=list;
        this.context=context;
        this.act=act;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listreff,parent,false);

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.title.setText(datalist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.postedby.setText(datalist.get(position).getPostedby());
        holder.postedon.setText(datalist.get(position).getDatetime());
        holder.likes.setText(datalist.get(position).getLikes());

        final String media=datalist.get(position).getMedia();
        final String tit=holder.title.getText().toString();
        Log.d("Harry Coooooovaaa", datalist.toString());
        seek=holder.seekBar;
        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                medialink=media;
                titlestring=tit;
                showProgress();
            Toast.makeText(context,medialink,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        downloadFile();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datalist.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title,postedby,likes,postedon;
        Button play;
        SeekBar seekBar;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audiotitle);

            title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audiotitle);
            postedby=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.postedby);
            postedon=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            likes=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            play=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.butplay);
            seekBar=(SeekBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


        }
    }


    private void showProgress(){
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Download Progress");


        cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
        cur_val.setText("Starting download...");
        dialog.show();

        pb = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        pb.setProgress(0);
    pb.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));
}
    private void downloadFile(){

        try {
            URL url = new URL(BASE_URL+medialink);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //connect
            urlConnection.connect();
            final String folder_main = "Apna";
            //set the path where we want to save the file
         /*   File SDCardRoot =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);

            if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) {
                SDCardRoot.mkdirs();
            }

            //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,title);*/



            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);
     //have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
       //create a File object for the output file
            final String perfection=titlestring.replaceAll("\"","");
            File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, perfection+".mp3");
       //now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation






            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
            totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setMax(totalSize);
                }
            });

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                // update the progressbar //
                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                        float per = ((float)downloadedSize/totalSize) * 100;
                        cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                    }
                });
            }
            //close the output stream when complete //
            fileOutput.close();
            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    dialog.dismiss();



                    try{
                    mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Apna/"+perfection+".mp3");//Write your location here
                        mp.prepareAsync();
                        //  mp.start();
                        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                                mRunnable.run();
                            }
                        });


                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });

        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
            Log.d("dfdsfsd", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.d("dfdsfsd", e.toString());
            showError("Error : IOException " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.d("dfdsfsd", e.toString());
            showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
        }
    }

    private void showError(final String err){
        act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("dfdsfsd", err);
            }
        });
    }


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mp != null) {

                //set max value
                int mDuration = mp.getDuration();

                seek.setMax(mDuration);

                //update total time text view

                //set progress to current position
                int mCurrentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();


                seek.setProgress((int) mp.getCurrentPosition());


                //  holder.seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);

                //update current time text view

                //handle drag on seekbar
                seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        if(mp != null && fromUser){
                            mp.seekTo(progress);
                        }
                    }
                });


            }

            //repeat above code every second
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    };
}
```

**MyActivity**

```
public class Recyclerviewaudio extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<List<GettingAudio>> arrylist;
    List<GettingAudio> mlist;
    AudiorecyclerAdapter audiorecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclerviewaudio);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.audiorecycler);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://zuman.ec3.amazonaws.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        Apicall api = retrofit.create(Apicall.class);

        Call<List<List<GettingAudio>>> call = api.GetAudio("Audio", "1", "0");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<List<GettingAudio>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<List<GettingAudio>>> call, Response<List<List<GettingAudio>>> response) {

                arrylist = response.body();
                mlist = arrylist.get(0);

                Log.d("Boooooodyyy", arrylist.toString());
                // Log.d("response code", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                // Log.d("response body", response.body().toString());
                audiorecyclerAdapter = new AudiorecyclerAdapter(Recyclerviewaudio.this, Recyclerviewaudio.this, mlist);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

                recyclerView.setAdapter(audiorecyclerAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<List<GettingAudio>>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Throwable", t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use seekBar=(SeekBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar); in Onclick

Example

```
public void onClick(View v){

    seekBar=(SeekBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

       .......
      //Yourcode
    }
```